# The number of permutations in a finite set such that $\sigma(i) \not= i $

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given a finite set $S$ with $|S|= n$, what is the number of permutations $\sigma$ such that

$$\sigma(i) \not= i,  \forall i \in S $$

That is, permutations where every element is interchanged with another element.
 (The permutations which can be described as one cycle containing exactly $n$ elements?)

My naive failed attempt at a solution:

$|S|= n$, consider the first element. We have $n-1$ places to put it. Considering the second element the number of choices depends on where we put the first element. I reckon it's either $n-1$ **or** $n-2$. And the problem continues since the next choice depends on the previous one. I'm Lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is about the number of permutations with 0 fixed points (i.e. [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)), which is given by $D_{n,0}=n!\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements) for a combinatorial proof. More generally, the number of permutations with $k$ fixed points is given by [rencontres numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers).

---

Regarding your question in parentheses: This is not the same as the number of permutations with exactly one cycle of length $n$. For example, the permutation $(1 2 3 4) \to (2 1 4 3)$ has two cycles, $(12)$ and $(34)$, but no fixed points. The number of permutations with one cycle is $(n-1)!$ (the [cycle notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_notation) of the permutation can be started with a fixed number, say $1$, after which the remaining $n-1$ numbers can be placed in any order).

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't know about rencontres numbers, interesting,  I shall immediately read up on this. Thanks again!